# Debug C# store byte array - byte[32] specific bytes in memory or just in inline code , how do you keep for testing

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

I want to copy from Visual Studio **Watch** a Byte Array 
Problem is that it displays vertically..

I need to hard code a byte array of 32 size ...

```
message.CalculatedMeasurement = new byte[] { 71, 107, 98, 101 };
```

Obviously above is ONLY byte[4]  , but I need/want to copy out all 32 that are in visual studio Watch in debug. .. thus  byte[32]   but the data looks like

```
   Name                               Value
   -----------------------------------------
  message.CalculatedMeasurement        {byte[32]}
        [0]                                 71
        [1]                                107
        .....                              ....
```

This obviously occurs 32 times..  but I want to be able to copy these byte array to clipboard and be able to hard code for testing in another application..

How do I do this?

Comment: write a function that displays the byte[] with the correct sytax u want, then call it from the immediate window when debuggin

Comment: Is this for a unit test?  I typically use base64 or hexadecimal encoding.

Comment: Well it is in a visual studio solution that while technically I could modify and check files out...  .. I was hoping to use the Watch or Immediate Window and spit it out like   -->  `71, 107, 98, 101 ...`    any chance i can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you can do that using `Quick Watch` window. Right click on `message.CalculatedMeasurement` while break point is on and select `Quick Watch`. In opened window you can write a small expression and evaluate it right there and try getting the formatted result

This is what talking about

[image]

Comment: Oh that is slick,  so in OP specific case , he could even just go to Watch and type   string.Join(",",message.CalculatedMeasurement)      very nice

Answer (score 1):

given `var bytes = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};`

while debugging, go to immediate window and do...

```
?bytes
```

it'll output :-

```
{int[12]}
    [0]: 1
    [1]: 2
    [2]: 3
    [3]: 4
    [4]: 5
    [5]: 6
    [6]: 7
    [7]: 8
    [8]: 9
    [9]: 10
    [10]: 11
    [11]: 12
```

or in immediate window

```
?string.Join(",",bytes)
```

you get

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"
```

[image]